# How to deduce this inequality from the assumptions?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality

> I am referring to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.05967v2.pdf), p. 22.

On that page, from the inequality

$$
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{H}(f^{n+1})-\mathbb{H}(f^n)+\Delta t\left(\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}-\eta\bar{m}_2\right)\Vert f^{n+1}-\rho^{n+1}\mathcal{M}\Vert_{2,\gamma}^2+\Delta t\eta\underline{m}_2\Vert\rho^{n+1}\Vert_2^2\\
&\leq\Delta t\eta\left(\sqrt{\overline{m}_4-\underline{m}_2^2}+\frac{C_P\sqrt{\overline{m}_2}}{\varepsilon}\right)\Vert f^{n+1} - \rho^{n+1}\mathcal{M}\Vert_{2,\gamma}\Vert\rho^{n+1}\Vert_2\tag{1}
\end{align*}
$$
the authors conclude that for any $\eta\in (0,\eta_2)$ with
$$
\eta_2:=\frac{\underline{m}_2}{(\sqrt{\overline{m}_4-\underline{m}_2^2}+C_P\sqrt{\overline{m}_2})^2+\underline{m}_2\overline{m}_2}\tag{2}
$$
and $\varepsilon\in (0,1)$ one has
$$
\mathbb{H}(f^{n+1})-\mathbb{H}(f^n)+\Delta t K(\eta)(\Vert f^{n+1}-\rho^{n+1}\mathcal{M}\Vert_{2,\gamma}^2+\Vert\rho^{n+1}\Vert_2^2)\leq 0\tag{3}
$$
with
$$
K(\eta)=\frac{1}{2}\min(1-\eta\overline{m}_2,\eta\underline{m}_2).\tag{4}
$$

Could somebody please explain to me how to deduce $(3)$?

I am trying for hours, but I simply do not get it. Is there some trick behind it?

I guess its a pure algebraic deduction and one does not need to know how all the notations appearing here are actually defined (this is why I omit the various definitions here...).

---

Actually, I have no concrete idea how to start.

To shorten the notation a little bit, I set
$$
x:=\Vert f^{n+1}-\rho^{n+1}\mathcal{M}\Vert_{2,\gamma},\qquad y:=\Vert\rho^{n+1}\Vert_2.
$$

Since $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$\small{
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{H}(f^{n+1})-\mathbb{H}(f^n)+\Delta t\left(\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}-\eta\bar{m}_2\right)x^2+\Delta t\eta\underline{m}_2y^2-\Delta t\eta\left(\sqrt{\overline{m}_4-\underline{m}_2^2}+\frac{C_P\sqrt{\overline{m}_2}}{\varepsilon}\right)xy\leq 0
\end{align*}}
$$

I guess that, in order to show $(3)$, one has to prove that, for $\eta\in (0,\eta_2)$ and $\varepsilon\in (0,1)$,
$$
\begin{align*}
K(\eta)(x^2+y^2)\leq\left(\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}-\eta\bar{m}_2\right)x^2+\eta\underline{m}_2y^2-\eta\left(\sqrt{\overline{m}_4-\underline{m}_2^2}+\frac{C_P\sqrt{\overline{m}_2}}{\varepsilon}\right)xy
\end{align*}
$$

(I did not manage to continue from here, however. It nearly drives me crazy.)

Answer (score 1):

*Remark*: Actually, the reasoning is easy.

Let
$$X = \Vert f^{n+1}-\rho^{n+1}\mathcal{M}\Vert_{2,\gamma}, \quad
Y = \Vert\rho^{n+1}\Vert_2$$
and
$$a = 1- \eta\overline{m}_2, \quad b = \eta\underline{m}_2, \quad c = \sqrt{\overline{m}_4-\underline{m}_2^2},
\quad d = C_P\sqrt{\overline{m}_2}, \quad
r = \min(a, b)$$
and
$$\quad s = \frac{1}{\varepsilon} > 1.$$

(1) is written as
$$\mathbb{H}(f^{n+1})-\mathbb{H}(f^n)
+ \Delta t\cdot (s^2 - 1 + a) X^2 + \Delta t\cdot b Y^2
\le \Delta t\cdot \eta (c + d s) XY$$
or
\begin{align*}
 &\mathbb{H}(f^{n+1})-\mathbb{H}(f^n)
 + \Delta t\cdot \frac{r}2 (X^2 + Y^2)\\
 \le{}& \Delta t\cdot \eta (c + d s) XY
 - \Delta t\cdot (s^2 - 1 + a) X^2
  - \Delta t\cdot b Y^2
 + \Delta t\cdot \frac{r}2 (X^2 + Y^2). 
\end{align*}

(3) is written as
$$\mathbb{H}(f^{n+1})-\mathbb{H}(f^n)
+ \Delta t\cdot \frac{r}2 (X^2 + Y^2) \le 0.$$

Thus, it suffices to prove that
$$\eta (c + d s) XY
-  (s^2 - 1 + a) X^2 - b Y^2
+  \frac{r}2 (X^2 + Y^2) \le 0.$$

Since $\frac{a}{2}X^2 + \frac{b}{2}Y^2 \ge \frac{r}{2}(X^2 + Y^2)$ (using $a \ge r$ and $b \ge r$), it suffices to prove that
$$\eta (c + d s) XY
-  (s^2 - 1 + a) X^2 - b Y^2
+  \frac{a}{2}X^2 + \frac{b}{2}Y^2 \le 0$$
or
$$\eta (c+ds)XY \le \frac{b}{2}Y^2 +  (s^2 + a/2 - 1)X^2.$$

By AM-GM, it suffices to prove that
$$4 \cdot \frac{b}{2} \cdot (s^2 + a/2 - 1) - \eta^2 (c + ds)^2 \ge 0$$
or
$$4 \cdot \frac{\eta\underline{m}_2}{2} \cdot (s^2 + (1- \eta\overline{m}_2)/2 - 1) - \eta^2 (c + ds)^2 \ge 0$$
or
$$4 \cdot \frac{\underline{m}_2}{2} \cdot (s^2 + (1- \eta\overline{m}_2)/2 - 1) - \eta (c + ds)^2 \ge 0$$
or
$$(2s^2 - 1)\underline{m}_2
\ge (c^2 + d^2s^2 + 2cds + \overline{m}_2\underline{m}_2)\eta$$
or
$$\eta \le \frac{(2s^2 - 1)\underline{m}_2}{c^2 + d^2s^2 + 2cds + \overline{m}_2\underline{m}_2}.$$

Thus, it suffices to prove that
$$\eta_2 = \frac{\underline{m}_2}{(c + d)^2 + \overline{m}_2\underline{m}_2} \le \frac{(2s^2 - 1)\underline{m}_2}{c^2 + d^2s^2 + 2cds + \overline{m}_2\underline{m}_2}$$
which is easy.

We are done.

Comment: Could you please comment on how you apply the AM-GM inequality? We have that $4XY\leq 2(X^2+Y^2)$.

Comment: @selector By AM-GM, we have $u + v \ge 2\sqrt{uv}$. So, $\frac{b}{2}Y^2 +  (s^2 + a/2 - 1)X^2
\ge 2\sqrt{\frac{b}{2}Y^2 \cdot  (s^2 + a/2 - 1)X^2}$. Then square both sides.

Comment: So you set $s:=\sqrt{b/2}Y$ and $u:=\sqrt{s^2+a/2-1)}X$ and then you apply $s^2+u^2\geq 2su$?

Comment: Let $u := \frac{b}{2}Y^2$ and $v :=  (s^2 + a/2 - 1)X^2$. Using AM-GM, we have $u + v \ge 2\sqrt{uv} = 2\sqrt{\frac{b}{2}Y^2 \cdot  (s^2 + a/2 - 1)X^2}$. It suffices to prove that $2\sqrt{\frac{b}{2}Y^2 \cdot  (s^2 + a/2 - 1)X^2} \ge \eta (c+ds)XY$. Squaring both sides, it suffices to prove that $4 \cdot \frac{b}{2} \cdot (s^2 + a/2 - 1) - \eta^2 (c + ds)^2 \ge 0$.

Comment: OK! Thanks. Last point: We need to have $u$ and $v$ to be non-negative in order to apply AM-GM. Hence, we need that $b/2\geq 0$ and $(s^2+a/2-1)\geq 0$. $b/2$ is non-negative, if we have $\eta>0$ (which is part of the assumptions. $s^2-1>0$ is also clear. So we need to have $a/2>0$ which is true if $\eta\overline{m}_2<1$. Is that also obvious?

Comment: @selector Because $\eta\in (0,\eta_2)$,  $\eta \overline{m}_2 \le \eta_2 \overline{m}_2 =\frac{\underline{m}_2 \overline{m}_2}{(\sqrt{\overline{m}_4-\underline{m}_2^2}+C_P\sqrt{\overline{m}_2})^2+\underline{m}_2\overline{m}_2} \le 1$.

Comment: Ah, I see!! That's the assumption on $\eta\in (0,\eta_2)$. Great. Thanks a lot, you made my day

Comment: @selector You are welcome.